# Ubuntu and windows not booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 14.10, windows-8, macosx

I had my mac tripple booted with Ubuntu and windows using refind and it took a long time to set up. Mac just did an update and now it will only boot to mac and the refind loaded doesn't show up any more. Will I have to restart the whole process or is there a why I can get my Ubuntu and windows partitions back without losing my previous data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you did your OSX update, all your partitions should still be there (definitely if you updated the standard way). You can double check that your Ubuntu and Windows partitions are still there in Disk Utility.

Did you just update to El Capitan? If so you need you first follow these steps:
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209272/how-do-i-get-refind-working-with-os-x-10-11-el-capitan

Then try installing rEFInd again, same way you did before.

If that doesn't work, I'd probably try removing and reinstalling rEFInd, which can be a bit tricky because by default it gets installed to the bootloader partition on your hard drive - a small 'hidden' partition.

Restart your computer then follow these steps to allow you to access the bootloader (EFI) partition. 
http://themacadmin.com/mounting-the-efi-boot-partition-on-mac-os-x/

In a terminal, to delete refind enter:

```
cd /Volumes/efi/./EFI
rm -rf refind
```

Then reinstall refind again.